# In MS excel I'am getting following error ! Enable macros and reopen work book

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run some excel macros but it is showing the error! 
"Because of your security settings macros have been disabled. To run macros, you need to reopen this workbook, And then choose to enable macros"

[image]

Comment: Unless you know and trust the author of the macros, just close the workbook and don't use it.  If you do trust the author, do what it says.

Comment: Really? Are you serious? You took a hard copy screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

Because by default macros will be disabled you need to enable it.

refer this document for enabling it

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12